# Are these questions duplicates? (And even if they are, should anything be done?)

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

[How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-a-list-in-python)

[What is the best way to copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184643/what-is-the-best-way-to-copy-a-list-in-python)

The second question was posted a couple of years before the first. Would they be worth merging? Should I flag the newer question as a duplicate?

Or is it not worth it with such old questions?

Answer (score 1):

[You should stop worrying and love dupes.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

No, they are not duplicates, no they are not worth merging.

Comment: Okay, cheers :)